# lower limit of $ \frac {|x+y\space|}{|x\space|+|y\space|} + \frac {|y+z\space|}{|y\space|+|z\space|} + \frac {|z+x\space|}{|z\space|+|x\space|}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $x,y,z$ be non-zero  real numbers . Then what is the minimum value (if exists) of $$ \frac {|x+y\space|}{|x\space|+|y\space|} + \frac {|y+z\space|}{|y\space|+|z\space|} + \frac {|z+x\space|}{|z\space|+|x\space|}$$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that two of $x,y,z$ must have the same signature, say they are $x,y$. Then $\frac{|x+y|}{|x|+|y|}=\frac{|x|+|y|}{|x|+|y|}=1$ and so $$\frac{|x+y|}{|x|+|y|}+\frac{|y+z|}{|y|+|z|}+\frac{|x+z|}{|x|+|z|}\geqslant1.$$

To achieve the equality, simply take $x=y=1,z=-1$, then the whole expression equals to 1, which is the min.

Comment: How do you know its **the** minimum value? What's the motivation?

Comment: @Inceptio, as mentioned, the whole expression is not less than 1 since the other two terms are nonnegative, so 1 will be a lower bound of the whole expression.

Comment: The proof isn't complete unless you show what happens if $x,y >1$ and $x,y<1$ and when $z \neq -1$.

Comment: @Inceptio, why need to justify $x,y>1$ or not? The thing that you need is to let $x=y=a$ and $z=-a$. The point is that I have showed that 1 is a lower bound, so the expression value cannot be lower than that. Thus, if you can find an achievable combination, then you are done.

Comment: @Easy: I get that that other two terms are non-negative, but how does that help proving that the expression is not less than $1$ ?

Comment: @SouvikDey, because the first term, as I showed, it is equal to 1.

Comment: @Easy: Well yes, you showed that, but you can never show $\frac{|x+y|}{|x|+|y|} ≥ 1 $ ! , so then how does showing that it is equal to $1$ prove that it is not less than $1$ ?

Comment: @SouvikDey, you need to read my first sentence. Two of $x,y,z$ have the same signature, so I am assuming they are $x,y$. If you assume they are $y,z$, then you will get the second term equal to 1. But the expression is symmetric, so it doesn't matter which two you choose. In whichever case, you will get at least one term equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Minium value is $1$, obtained by $(-1,1,1)$.

if $x,y,z>0$ or $x,y,z<0$ then greater than $1$.

w.l.o.g $x<0, y,z>0$ then results holds by both sides by 
$ (|x|+|y|)*(|x|+|z|)*(|z|+|y|)$